# is there a way to optimize this query's performance in Impala?

Tags: sql, performance, impala

This query involves 4 tables and cost 10.5 hours to complete:

Step1:

```
create table temp partitioned by (date_pull) stored as parquet as
select <fields>
from trans_ext -- this is the base table
inner join [shuffle] ac  -- fact_acc
inner join [shuffle] c  --related_acc
left join dt --trx_type
```

row count stats for the tables:

```
trans_ext: 8,289,244,895 (72 partitions)
ac: 985,164,794 (1 partitions)
c: 17,496,531 (1 partition)
dt 4: 369 (1 partition)
```

Step 2:
Create a count table h from temp

```
select related_cust, count(*) as ct from temp group by related_cust;
```

Step 3: Create final table by inner join the count table and apply a where clause

```
select t.* 
from temp t
inner join [shuffle] h on h.related_cust=t.related_cust
where  t.related_cust is not null
and h.ct <=1000000
order by t.related_cust;
```

I am thinking how can I eliminate the count table and create the final result directly? final table size: 19.6 billion rows.

Any thought? any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: it would be useful if you add the table columns for your source data and the columns used during the join (if you are using any)

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is remove the `order by` clause from your last query used to create your final table. This operation is really expensive and additional to that it does not add any value considering that the data will not be read sequentially so you are not gaining anything from it.

There could be other ways to implement the same query, it would be useful if you can explain the problem that you are trying to solve instead of the query used to solve it.